# Prolog - Multiply a matrix with a number

Tags: matrix, prolog

I'm new to prolog. I have a problem: Input a matrix and multiply that matrix with 4.
Here my code:

```
make_num_matrix(N,Matrix) :- make_matrix(N,N,Matrix).

make_matrix(_, N, []) :- N =< 0, !.
make_matrix(M, N, [R|Rs]) :-
    make_list(M,R),
    N2 is N - 1,
    make_matrix(M, N2, Rs).

make_list(N, [ ]) :- N =< 0, !.
make_list(N, [N | Rest]) :-
    N > 0,
    N2 is N - 1,
    make_list(N2, Rest).
```

In Prolog:

```
1 ?- make_num_matrix(4,M).
```

And the result:

```
M = [[4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]].
```

But I don't know how to multiply this matrix (M) with 4.
Please, help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you represent a matrix as a list of lists, [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply)/3 it's the simpler way to go

```
multiply_matrix(I, N, O) :- maplist(multiply_list(N), I, O).
multiply_list(N, I, O) :- maplist(multiply(N), I, O).
multiply(N, I, O) :- O is I * N.

?- make_num_matrix(4,M),multiply_matrix(M,4,R).
M = [[4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]],
R = [[16, 12, 8, 4], [16, 12, 8, 4], [16, 12, 8, 4], [16, 12, 8, 4]].
```